# Compare 3 ordered lists to make 4th list containing all elements in order

Tags: python, list

I have three reports in Excel which I'm joining with Python module OpenPyXl. Each report has two columns: First column has labels and second column has values:

```
| apple  | 20 | 
| banana | 10 |
| carrot | 5  |
```

When joining reports, each label must line up:

```
|        | R1 | R2 | R3 |
| apple  | 20 | 10 |  5 | 
| banana | 10 |    | 10 |
| carrot | 5  | 10 |
```

Clearly, if R2 doesn't have a score for banana, we don't want to have the carrot score on the banana line. (^_^)

My thought is to first create lists of labels for each report:

```
lst1 = ["zucchini","apple","banana","carrot","carrot","escarole"]
lst2 = ["apple","carrot","escarole","squash"]
lst3 = ["zucchini","apple","escarole","squash"]
```

(As you can see, lst1 has carrot twice. This is not a mistake. In the report context it's actually a header. And, order matters as with zucchini first.).

Then, create a fourth ordered list containing all of the elements of all three lists--including duplicates:

```
lst4 = ["zucchini","apple","banana","carrot","carrot","escarole","squash"]
```

Finally, I can compare each of the original lists to the 4th list and when label's don't match, update from the master list.

How can I create the 4th list?

Comment: Can you use pandas? Beccause the task would become trivial with it.

Comment: You can do this with defaultdict simulating a Counter, if the duplicates always occur consecutively within a single report.

Comment: @Andreas, _"Can you use pandas?"_ The plan is to use the resulting 4th as line number lookup dictionary for other OpenPyXl tasks. If the task is truly trivial to generate the 4th list, then I'm good with using Pandas. Absolutely. And, the project does not have performance requirements.

Comment: @Kenny Ostrom, what sort of algorithm are you thinking would let me compare all three reports, and keep order?

Comment: Start with an empty defaultdict(int) as the accumulator. Iterate through the lists, making a counter instance. Merge it with the accumulator by taking the max of each key. I had to simulate collections.Counter with collections.defaultdict(int) to avoid having it reorder them by their counts. Then reconstruct from the accumulator assuming that multiple instances of the same key are always grouped together.

Comment: So ... how do you know which "carrot" to line up with which "carrot" if there are multiples? How do you line things up if they are in different orders in the different reports? It feels like you're ignoring your own constraints when convenient. It would be so much easier use set operations on the headers, and just sum the values. Or merge the labels but store them in a defaultdict(list), appending each number to a list so you know all the distinct counts.

Comment: @Kenny Ostrom, The first duplicate is always a header. The reports generally match within 2-5 records out of a total of 300 lines. I can't run a set, because these are not 'data' reports which lend themselves to Pandas solutions. These are Excel financial reports which have a specific format and order. That's why I started with OpenPyXl. Everything with OPXL is an iteration. I'm thinking the algorithm needs a lookahead. Or maybe the rows broken into chunks when a mismatch is found, and a second pass sorts them out...

Answer (score 1):

Here full working example with pandas:

**Sample data:**

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
d1 = {'labels': {0: 'apple', 1: 'banana', 2: 'carrot'}, 'values': {0: 20, 1: 10, 2: 5}}
d2 = {'labels': {0: 'apple', 1: 'carrot'}, 'values': {0: 20, 1: 10}}
d3 = {'labels': {0: 'apple', 1: 'banana'}, 'values': {0: 5, 1: 10}}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1).set_index('labels')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2).set_index('labels')
df3 = pd.DataFrame(d3).set_index('labels')
```

**Code:**

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1)
df.columns = ['R1', 'R2', 'R3']
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)

        R1    R2    R3
apple   20  20.0   5.0
banana  10   NaN  10.0
carrot   5  10.0   NaN
```

---

Should you still really need that 4th list you can do this instead:

```
lst = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).index.tolist()
print(lst)

['apple', 'banana', 'carrot', 'apple', 'carrot', 'apple', 'banana']
```

---

Or for the 3 lists as input you can use a custom function without pandas:

```
lst1 = ["zucchini","apple","banana","carrot","carrot","escarole"]
lst2 = ["apple","carrot","escarole","squash"]
lst3 = ["zucchini","apple","escarole","squash"]

def list4(lsts):
    out = list()
    namespace = list()

    for lst in lsts:
        for element in lst:
            if element not in namespace:
                out.append(element)
        namespace = set(out)
    return out

list4([lst1, lst2, lst3])
# Out[90]: ['zucchini', 'apple', 'banana', 'carrot', 'carrot', 'escarole', 'squash']
```

Comment: The three lists following the table illustration include some of the unusual constraints like repeat labels. I tried this approach (`pd.DataFrame({'label': ["zucchini","apple","banana","carrot","carrot","escarole"]}).set_index('label')`) and the extra carrot was dropped: `zucchini, apple, banana, carrot, escarole, squash`

Comment: @xtian can you please provide a sample input and output? Because based on you sample tables its hard to guess how the list would result out of it, because the tables and the list differ in data. You also wrote that: "each label must line up" what happens in case carrot was mentioned twice in the first table with the carrot values of the other tables?

Comment: ?? I did provide sample input and output--four lists. The minimum problem is having 3 reports sharing mostly-matching row labels, and generating a new list of labels all reports have in common. Do you understand? Regarding the Carrot example, the first label is always a header and the subsequent labels line up to values--its just a constraint of the input. What's important as I mention in the OP is that repetition is maintained in the output. I'll address the issue of what's a header and what's a feature separately. I just need the final list to have the noted properties.

Comment: @xtian added a custom function to get the 4th list.

Comment: That doesn't account for duplication in a later row, where there was a single instance in a previous row. Try list4(reversed([lst1, lst2, lst3)]